# SlidingMenu's shadow feature not rendering properly

Tags: android, xml, slidingmenu

I've just recently implemented jfeinstein10's SlidingMenu library in my Android app and so far it's been quite nice. However, one problem I haven't been able to resolve is getting the shadow (i.e. `setShadowDrawable()`) feature to work. No matter what I do, the shadow seems to:

1. Draw at the left side of the rectangle defined by the shadow width, which is the opposite of what should be happening as the drawer is on the left side of the screen, and
2. Draw in the opposite direction - being a gradient, one would expect it to be approximately #000000 at the right and fade towards the left, but it's doing the opposite.

Here's the code I'm using to build the SlidingMenu (note the `setShadowWidthRes()` and `setShadowDrawable()` calls):

```
SlidingMenu navDrawer = new SlidingMenu(this);
navDrawer.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
navDrawer.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
navDrawer.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width); // this is 25dp
navDrawer.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.drawer_shadow);
navDrawer.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
navDrawer.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
navDrawer.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
navDrawer.setMenu(R.layout.navdrawer_layout);
```

...and here's the drawer_shadow drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FF000000"
        android:endColor="#00000000"/>

</shape>
```

...and here's an image of the issue in action:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just use the standard navigation drawer in the Android framework? Might be easier to get working

Comment: That's what I was initially using, actually. I just prefer SlidingMenu.

Comment: Plus, I don't think the native one even *has* a shadow, in which case this issue wouldn't sway me either way.

Comment: If by "show" you mean shadow, then I can tell you that the native NavigationDrawer does have a shadow, not sure whether or not you can assign a custom drawable though.